# Fetch XML return option set value for Dynamics Portals liquid

Tags: liquid, microsoft-dynamics, fetchxml

I am trying to return an option set value / label to Dynamics portals site and struggling with the syntax, any help would be much appreciated. I cant get the optionset label to display which i what i would ideally like.

```
    {% fetchxml utilisation_stats %}
    <fetch version="1.0" output-format="xml-platform" mapping="logical" distinct="false">
        <entity name="contact">
            <attribute name="contactid" />
            <filter type="and">
                <condition attribute="contactid" operator="eq" uitype="contact" value="{{ user.Id }}" />
            </filter>
            <link-entity name="account" from="accountid" to="parentcustomerid" visible="false" link-type="outer"
                alias="acc_exec_data">
                <attribute name="name" />
                <attribute name="new_optionset" />
            </link-entity>
        </entity>
    </fetch>
    {% endfetchxml %}



<div class="container" style="">
    <div class="row">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name"
            value="{% for result in utilisation_stats.results.entities %} {{ result['acc_exec_data.name'] | string }} {% endfor %}">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="eventsAttended"
            value="{% for result in utilisation_stats.results.entities %} {{ result['acc_exec_data.new_optionset'] | string }} {% endfor %}">
    </div>
 </div>
```

I am just wanting to get back the label for the option set, when i run the fetch in FetchXML tester and it returns the optionset value of 1000000 but i cant even get that to be displayed.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

I'm using code that looks like this... '.label' is the clincher.

```
  <div name="content" style="padding: 15px 30px 0 0; clear: both;">
     {{ result.imech_name | escape }} 
    
    <div name="main-content" style="margin-left: 300px; max-width: 800px;">
        <p> {{ result.imech_type.label | escape }} </p>
        <br />                  
    </div>              
    <div class="clear"></div>
  </div>
```

Comment: And for those looking for the syntax for the value of the option set, it's `.value`. So `result.imech_type.value`

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted to keep the same syntax of using a string in the fetch result object, you could do something like the either of the following, depending on what you're after:

```
{{ result['acc_exec_data.new_optionset'].label }}
```

or

```
{{ result['acc_exec_data.new_optionset'].value }}
```